# How to get an image from firebase storage using the GUI of firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

So I uploaded an image to the firebase storage and I refference it in a user collection like that:

```
displayname: "David"
avatar: gs:/news-14b77.appspot.com/avatar Images/david.jpg
```

now I want to get that object in my project (React) and to view that image, the object i get when i console log it is that:

```
displayname: David, 
avatar: n,
```

how do I get the image there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gs:/news-14b77.appspot.com/avatar Images/david.jpg` is a URL type that is only usable with the Firebase Storage and Cloud Storage SDKs. You can't directly add it to an `img` view, as that won't know what to do with the `gs:/` protocol.

So you'll need to use the Firebase SDK to convert the `gs:/` URL to a so-called download URL, which is a URL that gives public read-only access to the file. That's be something like:

```
var ref = firebase.storage().refFromURL('gs:/news-14b77.appspot.com/avatar Images/david.jpg');
ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
  // in here you can set the URL for the avatar
});
```

Or (using `await`):

```
let ref = firebase.storage().refFromURL('gs:/news-14b77.appspot.com/avatar Images/david.jpg');
let url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
// here you can set the URL for the avatar
```

For more examples of this, see the Firebase documentation on [getting data via a url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).